# PMT Javascript function not returning expected results

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to calculate loan repayments using the PMT function. I have attempted to recreate this in Javascript using the following formula, but the results are not what I am expecting. All of the variables are returning the expected values:

```
var pv = loan amount
var fv = future value
var i = interestrate
var n = numberofpayments

var repayment = (pv - (fv / (Math.pow(1 + i), n))) / (1 - (1 / Math.pow(1 + i), n) / i);
```

I am most likely using the incorrect Javascript syntax somewhere (I am fairly new to Javascript), or it could be an error with my formula, so any help would be much appreciated.

Using the following example:

```
pv = 10000
fv = 5000
i = 0.25
n = 36
```

I am getting the following output from the above formula: -68.96

This is incorrect, the correct result should be around: 158

Formula based on: http://www.tvmcalcs.com/index.php/calculators/apps/lease_payments

Comment: your problem is that you have Math.pow(1 + i), n. Should be Math.pow(1+i,n)

Comment: `Math.pow` requires two arguments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Comment: @J. Ayo I have updated my answer with the corrected formula. Note that i should be divided by 12, and that you need to use pow(...,-n) not pow(..., n). I confirmed my answer with Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work:

```
   var pv = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
   var i = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value, 10) / 1200;
   var n = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
   var fv = parseFloat(document.repaymentcalc.finalpayment.value, 10);

   var repayment = ( pv - (fv / Math.pow((1 + i), n))) / ((1 - (1 / Math.pow((1 + i), n))) / i);
```

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you have Math.pow(1 + i), n. Should be Math.pow(1+i,n)

```
var repayment = (pv - (fv / (Math.pow(1 + i, n)))) / (1 - (1 / Math.pow(1 + i, n)) / i);
```

--- update

Here is the correct formula:

```
var pv = 10000;
var fv = 5000;
var i = 0.25 / 12;
var n = 36;

function payment() {
  return (pv - fv) * (i) / (1 - (Math.pow(1 + i, -n)));
}
```

Comment: @J.Ayo that's not helpful. Try adding some example input and output to your question if you want answers that address mathematical errors in your code.

Comment: I don't know what future value is doing in your formula. I think you are confused. Repayment is based on 3 things: loan amount, interest rate, and number of periods https://www.easycalculation.com/mortgage/loan-payment-amount.php

Comment: @J.Ayo then your original logic is wrong and you haven't given us any context to help you with that.

Comment: Have added example input and output

Comment: @ControlAltDel - this is a loan with a future value. I.e. not repaid in full by the end date. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-pmt-function